# Enabling stream access in Red5 1.0 RC1

Tags: flash, security, video-streaming, red5

I have to fiddle around with video on clients that are getting the video stream from Red5, and I'm getting flash security errors when trying to do so.
How to enable that?

Comment: Could you post an example of the errors?

Comment: SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: file:///C:/Users/some/path/branches/cleanup/dbg/main.swf cannot access rtmp://some.ip/SFS_RedBox. No policy files granted access.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://trac.red5.org/ticket/498

And add this to your red5-web.xml in red5/live/

```
<property name="audioAllowed" value="true"/>
<property name="videoAllowed" value="true"/>
```

Comment: At the time I've asked this question, there was not such option or it did not work. Thanks though, blast from the past.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open the flash file from your IIS .It will work fine .i also encountered the same problem sometimes.Cheers